# Spring not finding Hibernate in Eclipse Maven Project when using WTP

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, m2e

I can successfully deploy my project to a webserver, but when deploying to the Eclipse Apache Tomcat Instance, I cannot start my app due to the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:429)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:412)
    ...
```

I have WTP installed, I have run update configuration, but it's possible i did not do them in the correct order as one of you out there who have dealt with this problem.  I have verified that this class is available under "Maven Dependencies" inside my spring-2.5.5 jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the answer is: check the build path, make sure that a SPECIFIC server runtime is also specified...  somehow through my tweaking with wtp and other stuff, i managed to lose my server runtime (probably because i deleted and re-built it).